# How do you plot a limited number of bars in pandas or seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a huge dataset with hundreds of cities. I want to make a bar chart with just the 50 most occurring cities.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
base_color = sb.color_palette()[0]
cat_order = planes_df['OriginCityName'].value_counts().index
plt.figure(figsize = [11, 5])
sb.countplot(data = planes_df, x = 'OriginCityName', color = base_color, order = cat_order)
plt.title('# of planes that takeoff from the origin state')
plt.xlabel('Origin States')
plt.ylabel('Number of Planes')
plt.xticks(rotation = 90);
```

This plots hundreds of cities. How can I just plot the 50 most frequest cities?

[image: bar chart]

I know there must be a limiter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the `.head()` after sorting using `.sort_values()` and assign that to `cat_order`:

`planes_df['OriginCityName'].value_counts().sort_values().head(50).index`

Comment: That gives me an empty graph. :(

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: This worked: cat_order = planes_df['OriginCityName'].value_counts().head(50).index
Can you edit your answer?